# If jQuery is made up of JavaScript syntax at its core, why browser support was added explicitely for it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-support

On many places, I found that jQuery is made on top of JavaScript. So the browser that supports JavaScript would definitely support jQuery.

But the page on Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks#Browser_support suggests browser support was added at its specific version. I am also confused on the statement at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery#Browser_support

May be I am unnecessarily confused, but this is a bit causing me headache.

Can anyone please tell me about this?

Comment: There are features of JS which do not work in all browsers, therefore if a framework uses a non-supported feature it affects the minimum browser level.

Comment: I think it depends if a browser has implemented all javascript features that jQuery is using.

Comment: Also note that your first link suggests that jQuery supports IE6, however this is only for the 1.x branch. From 2.x onwards a lot of legacy code was removed and it now only supports IE9+

Comment: Simplify this down to ... just like there are different versions of browsers, there are different versions of javascript. Newer versions of each support features that are not backward compatible

Comment: Software is not static, therefore, "X supports Y" is not very informative,  "X version A supports Y version B" is more like it. This applies to both Javascript (the language) and DOM (the browser object model, which jquery primarily deals with).

Comment: Thanks all, 
May be it was actually a basic thing I should understand. However, comments here have explained me better than I could on my own.

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript: It supports directly. we don't require to add any library file.

Jquery: While we are using jquery, we have to add jquery library file. Without library, browser won't understand jquery script. Each library version, covers new feature of browser. so based on broswer version, we can use specific version's jquery library.